# Aggregate function of column that has at least one type of value in a different column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table below as

```
ID | Blood_Type |  Size
B2     A           100
B2     B           200
C2     C           102
C2     O            88
G4     I            44
G4     A            100
```

How can I query my table above to get average of only my IDs that have at least have one row with blood type of A

Expected output:

```
ID | Avg_Size 
B2    150
G4     72
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim's answer is good, a simpler albeit perhaps not how you would want to do it, other way, is doing [HAVING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html) in long form

```
SELECT id,
    avg_size
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
        AVG(size) AS avg_size,
        SUM(IFF(blood_type = 'A', 1, 0)) AS a_count
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
)
WHERE a_count > 1;
```

so you can ether use SUM or COUNT, they both ignore nulls, which is the implicit result of Tim's `CASE WHEN Blood_Type = 'A' THEN 1 END` is the same as

```
CASE 
    WHEN Blood_Type = 'A' THEN 1 
    ELSE NULL
END
```

if you use SUM it can handle null's or zeros thus the [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) can be used, which I like as it's smaller and more explicit about what is happening.

thus Tim's answer can be swapped to a `SUM(IFF`
like:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    AVG(size) AS avg_size
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(IFF(Blood_Type = 'A',1, 0) > 0;
```

Comment: `SUM(IFF(Blood_Type = 'A',1, 0) > 0` could be swapped with `COUNT_IF(Blood_Type='A') > 0` [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda wow. boom! for even more reduction and clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You may try aggregation here with an assertion in the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT ID, AVG(Size) AS Avg_Size
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Blood_Type = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```